# Angular + Breeze get entity from metadata without fetching results

Tags: angularjs, breeze

Hi there i want to create a form based on the metadata retrieved from breeze to leverage the validation.  However, I can't manage to find a way to get specific entity from the Metadata without loading the result.

Is it possible to load 1 entity from metadata and bind it to a view?

I tried using the `var entityMetaData = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType(“Order”);`  but this throws the following exception Heading

```
Breeze: Unable to locate a 'Type' by the name: 'Order'. Be sure to execute a query or call fetchMetadata first
```

so i tried to get the entity from the rawMetadata using by fetching it. But this doesn't seem to work as rawmetadata does not have `getEntityType` function.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var controllerId = 'login';

    angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['$location', 'authcontext','breeze', login]);

    function login($location, authcontext, breeze) {
        var vm = this;

        var manager = null;
        var entityTypeName = "Order";
        breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
        manager = new breeze.EntityManager('http://localhost:54078/breeze/breeze');

        manager.metadataStore.fetchMetadata('http://localhost:54078/breeze/breeze').then(function (rawMetadata) {
            vm.orderModels = rawMetadata.getEntityType(entityTypeName);  //,-- this does not work..
        });

    }
})();
```

What could i be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The metadataStore has the metadata after the MetadataStore.fetchMetadata promise returns. i.e.

```
 manager.metadataStore.fetchMetadata('http://localhost:54078/breeze/breeze').then(function () {
        vm.orderModels = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType(entityTypeName);  
 });
```